# Cannot loop through items in JSON (php)

Tags: php, json, loops

i have the following Json sent via ajax to test.php:

```
[{},{"product[]":"john","qty[]":"12","price[]":"100","total[]":"1200"},{"product[]":"juan","qty[]":"22","price[]":"3.5","total[]":"77"},{"product[]":"louis","qty[]":"99","price[]":"1.22","total[]":"120.78"},{"product[]":"paul","qty[]":"5","price[]":"2.1","total[]":"10.5"},{"product[]":"carl","qty[]":"9","price[]":"14","total[]":"126"},{"total_amount":"1533.00"}]
```

In my php file I am trying to loop through each individual product[], qty[], price[] and list values:

```
<?php
    $obj = json_decode($_POST["mydata"]);
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

   // echo json_encode($obj[1]->{'product[]'}); //(works)


foreach($obj as $item) {


echo $item['product[]'].'<br>';
echo $item['price[]'].'<br>';
echo $item['qty[]'].'<br>';
echo $item['total[]'].'<br>';     
     }

?>
```

but this throws an error.
What is wrong in my loop?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things wrong with the code, the first is that you decode as objects and try and use this as an array.  You need to pass `true` as the second parameter to `json_decode()` to make it an associative array.

The second is that your array contains elements which don't have all of the details.  The last element only has `"total_amount"`, so none of the other fields exist.  This is why I use

```
if ( isset($item['product[]'])){
```

to check the object before outputting the data...

```
$obj = json_decode($_POST["mydata"], true);
header('Content-Type: application/json');

foreach($obj as $item) {
    if ( isset($item['product[]'])){
        echo $item['product[]'].'<br>';
        echo $item['price[]'].'<br>';
        echo $item['qty[]'].'<br>';
        echo $item['total[]'].'<br>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass `true` as second argument to [`json_decode`](http://www.php.net/json_decode).

Per the documentation:

> **assoc**
>
> When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

So your code becomes:

```
$obj = json_decode($_POST["mydata"], true);
```

Also note that the first entry in your array is empty, so you're gonna have to check for that.